# Search Bar Cancel Button with RxSwift

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

When the cancel button of the search bar is tapped I want to resign the keyboard but the current issue is that my function to handle the cancel button is not working.. You can see my code here:

```
searchBar.rx.cancelButtonClicked
                .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
                .drive(onNext: { [searchBar] in
                    searchBar?.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                    
                    
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `searchBar` is the actual searchBar on the `UISearchController`...

You have to call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` and also for iOS 13 and above I have found that the cancel button won't disappear without calling `searchBar.showsCancelButton = false` as well.

Furthermore I recommend to pass a weak instance of the searchBar or your code might leak. Therefore here's how I would write it:

```swift
searchBar.rx
   .cancelButtonClicked
   .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
   .drive(onNext: { [weak searchBar] in
      searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()
      searchBar?.showsCancelButton = false    
   })
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```